# How to set html5 canvas's context property by json format?

Tags: javascript, json, html, canvas

We all know to set canvas's context property like this:

```
ctx.textBaseline = "top";
ctx.shadowColor = "#000";
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 10;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
ctx.shadowBlur = 10;
```

But if I have json format data like this:

```
{textBaseline: "top",
shadowColor: "#000",
shadowOffsetX: 10,
shadowOffsetY: 0,
shadowBlur: 10}
```

How to set ctx's property by the above data?

I can do like that:

```
function setctxproperty(jsondata) {
    if (jsondata[textBaseline]) {
        ctx.textBaseline = jsondata[textBaseline]; 
    } else if (jsondata[shadowColor]) {
        ctx.shadowColor = jsondata[shadowColor]; 
    } else if (...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Do you have any good way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a better way. You can use something like this:

```
function setProps(data) {
   for (var p in data) {
     if (!data.hasOwnProperty(p)) continue;
     ctx[p] = data[p];
   }
}
```

Comment: You should add [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) when using for..in

Comment: Yes, I forgot about it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. But why " if (!data.hasOwnProperty(p)) continue; "? I use " if (!ctx.hasOwnProperty(p)) continue; " instead. Then it cannot work.

Comment: Thanks. I known that "The for in statement allows for looping through the names of all of the properties of an object including those inherited throught the prototype chain." from jshint.